# Extending serializable class behavior

Tags: java

I have a class `Foo` which implements `Serializable`  and I wanted to serialize `name`. Now I want to serialize  `mobile number`.
Does my extended class  `Moo` need to implement `Serializable`?
Does my extended class  `Moo` need  its own `serialVersionUID`?

```
Class Foo implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5073774854914426595L;

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ClassUtils.toString(this);
    }

}
```

I am extending  this class

```
Class Moo extends Foo{
  String mobileNumber;

 public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ClassUtils.toString(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does my extended class Moo need to implement Serializable?" it already does.

Comment: Check out *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 74: "Implement `Serializable` judiciously", to see what it warns about when mixing Serializable and inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Moo class doesn't need to implement Serializable
2. Yes, it has to have it own serialVersionUID

Comment: "dosen't need to implement Serializable" not directly; but it *does* implement it already.